# How to pass jQuery variable into PHP file using cookies

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I used for this code pass jQuery variable data into PHP file but does not worked on this code. does not get cookie value on PHP file.... how to solve this problem...

My jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = 1;
    ownerEdit(data);
});

function ownerEdit(id) {
    document.cookie = 'id=id';
}
```

I was passed the cookie value for PHP file...

My PHP code:

```
$id = $_COOKIE['editid'];
print_r($id);
```

Does not get cookie value on PHP file....

Comment: Look at the names, one uses editid, the other just uses id.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this

```
function ownerEdit(id) {
    document.cookie = 'editid = ' + id;
}
```

Comment: its working thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

**Set cookie in JavaScript**

```
 document.cookie = 'editid='+id+'; expires=Fri, 30 Nov 2016 20:47:11 UTC; path=/'
```

**Complete code as follows**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var data = 1;
  ownerEdit(data);
});

function ownerEdit(id) {
  document.cookie = 'editid='+id+'; expires=Fri, 30 Nov 2016 20:47:11 UTC; path=/';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the issue in your line

`document.cookie='id=id';`

this just sets the string "id" to your cookie. Also your cookie has the wrong name.

So try the following:

`document.cookie='editid ='+id`